# Where can I deploy my java REST webservice for free so that I can access it remotely?

Tags: java, web-services, azure, webserver

I have developed a REST web-service in Java interacting with a MySQL database.I want to deploy the web-service and the create a database at a server so that I can invoke it from an application.I tried Microsoft Azure but was unable to get it done.Where can I find relevant information for this?

Comment: Guys !! Thanks for your input. I have ultimately used the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk framework to deploy the webservice and created a RDS instance to interact with it. If anyone else is facing the same problem, you can try the AWS EBS Framework. It is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with a MySQL database using the third party option in the Azure Marketplace from ClearDb. What I ended up doing was switching my database from a MySQL instance to an Azure Database Instance (Subset of SQL Server's features.) This worked **perfectly** for me! I was able to query from my database feed data to my api, and access the API through my Azure Web App.

I understand this may not be an option for you, however, [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04) is a great cloud hosting option (with scaling similar to Azure, although not as good in my honest opinion.) You can set up a Linux Environment with a MySQL Server and JVM and serve your whole API through there. Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

@coderden, According to your description, I think you have been deployed your Java Application on an Azure WebApp. Then when you created a MySQL database on Azure for connection from the Java webapp, please make sure the webapp & mysql instance created in a same resource group and note the connection string of MySQL on Azure.

As reference, please see the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/#create-a-mysql-database-in-azure-portal) to try again although it's for PHP, the steps are the same for Java.